# How to differentiate model types from xgboost XGBRFClassifier and XGBClassifier

Tags: python, xgboost, isinstance

I'm building a module that supports both `XGBClassifier` and `XGBRFClassifier` from `xgboost`. I want to differentiate them in my module but I noticed that:

```py
from xgboost import XGBRFClassifier, XGBClassifier

xgbrf_model = XGBRFClassifier()
isinstance(xgbrf_model, XGBClassifier) # True
```

This should obviously not be true. I want to stick to `isinstance` and not try:

```py
type(xgbrf_model) == XGBClassifier # False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This should obviously not be true ..`isinstance(XGBRFClassifier(), XGBClassifier)`

As of XGBoost version v1.7.3, the `XGBRFClassifier` class is a direct subclass of the `XGBClassifier` class:
https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/v1.7.3/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py#L1627

Therefore, this `isinstance` check correctly evaluates to `True`.

Your best bet is to perform checks from more specific classes to less specific classes. That is, check for `XGBRFClassifier` first, and if that evaluates to `False`, only then check for `XGBClassifier`.